# Is $x_n = (−1)^n$, $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$ convergent in $(\mathbb{R}, \cal{T} )$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\cal{T}$ = {$∅, \mathbb{R}$} ∪ {$(−a, a) : a ∈ (0, ∞)$} be a topology on $\mathbb{R}$.
Is the sequence $(x_n)_n∈\mathbb{N}$ defined by $x_n = (−1)^n$, $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$, convergent in $(\mathbb{R}, \cal{T} )$? In this case, what does it
converge to?
I think it depends on the parity of n, because it would alternate between -1 and 1, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence converges to any number $x$ such that $|x| \geq 1$. Consider any open set $(-a,a)$ such that $x$ lies in this set. Then $(-1)^{n}$ lies in $(-a,a)$ for all $n$ . Thus $x_n \to x$.

Comment: The set $(-a,a)$ is not open if we are working with $\mathcal{T}=\left\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\right\}$.

Comment: @charlus That is not OP's defin ition of $\tau$.

Comment: You are of course correct! :)

Comment: So is the sequence convergent?

Comment: @Beni It is convergent. The limit is not unique.